# (Solucionado)arreglo en java al ingresar 2 palabras en una misma direccion de array

Tags: java, array

En clase estamos viendo arreglos en java y me piden un programa que:

1. Pida cuantos nombres desea ingresar.
2. Los imprima.

algo así:

```
[0] = "Alejandro Sanchez";
[1] = "Fernando Ortega";
```

Lo unico que he podido hacer es ingresar una palabra al arreglo. así:

```
[0] = "Alejandro"
[1] = "Sanchez"
```

**Solucionado, agregar un segundo Scanner, uno para almacenar el tamaño del array y el otro para almacenar los datos del array**

```
package ejer24tap_vectornombres;
import java.util.*;
/**
*
* @author Carlos Vazquez Lara, 4S11.
*/
public class Ejer24Tap_vectornombres {
    public Ejer24Tap_vectornombres(){
        Scanner lee=new Scanner(System.in);//almacena el tamaño del array
        Scanner lee1=new Scanner(System.in);//almacena los datos del array
        int tam=0;
        System.out.println("Cuantos nombres desea ingresar: ");
        tam=lee.nextInt();
        String[] nombres = new String[tam];
        for (int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
            System.out.prinln("Ingrese el nombre #"+i);
            nombres[i]=lee1.next();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < nombres.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Nombre ["+j+"] "+nombres[j]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Ejer24Tap_vectornombres();

    }

}
```

Comment: y que haz intentado? las tearas escolares son bien recibidas siempre y cuando quien pregunta agregue lo que ha intentado aunque sea mínimo y muestre un esfuerzo, de otra manera se entiendo que quieres lo hagamos por ti y asi solo terminará cerrada tu pregunta; revisa [ask]

Comment: gracias por el comentario, y si tienes razón, no es mi intención que lo hagan por mi, he buscado en libros que tengo a la mano y en internet, por las prisas no leí el apartado de como preguntar esta es mi primer pregunta respecto a algún código

Comment: no hay problema se bienvenido, tal vez por la hora debas esperar un poco a la participación de la comunidad pero ya muestras un avance mucho éxito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al hacer `lee.next()` dentro del for te va a cojer el primer token y los espacios separan tokens por eso te ocurre lo que dices.

Tienes que usar `lee.nextLine()` para que te coja la línea entera.

En tu ejemplo

```
for (int i= 0; i<nombres.lenght;i++){
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre #"+i);
    nombres[i]=lee.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda. En efecto con nextLine(); pude almacenar un nombre completo, pero empieza a pedir el nombre saltandose un espacio y al mostrar los nombres la posicion "0" aparece en blanco.

Answer (score 0):

no deberías utilizar Scanner para este tipo de problemas. De acuerdo a la documentación del JDK, Scanner es un colector de tokens simple que recibe un InputStream nada más, es por eso que el método `next` te está devolviendo cada "palabra" en cada posición. Sin embargo, la clase también tiene un método para poder leer una línea completa `Scanner::nextLine`. Puedes chequear la documentación oficial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--

Comment: muchas gracias lo checare